# PHP Mysql GET Last month and current month data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to retrieve m last month data and current month data

my query works correctly as

last month data calculate 1 month from current date. But i want my data calculate as calander month not from my current date.

like

my current date is 2014-07-23

now my calculation return data by calculating month from my current date.

but I want to get based on calendar jan,feb,march range.

my current query of last month

```
SELECT (100*AVG((m.carbs)/((m.carbs)+(m.fat)+(m.protein)))) AS Percantage_carbs,(100*AVG((m.fat)/((m.carbs)+(m.fat)+(m.protein)))) AS Percantage_fat,(100*AVG((m.protein)/((m.carbs)+(m.fat)+(m.protein)))) AS Percantage_protein
FROM `meal` AS m,`user_history` as u where u.meal_id=m.id and u.user_id=$user_id and date(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create)) BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()
```

my current query of this month

```
SELECT (100*AVG((m.carbs)/((m.carbs)+(m.fat)+(m.protein)))) AS Percantage_carbs,(100*AVG((m.fat)/((m.carbs)+(m.fat)+(m.protein)))) AS Percantage_fat,(100*AVG((m.protein)/((m.carbs)+(m.fat)+(m.protein)))) AS Percantage_protein
FROM `meal` AS m,`user_history` as u where u.meal_id=m.id and u.user_id=$user_id and YEARWEEK(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last month

```
year(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))) = year(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
and month(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))) = month(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

THis month

```
year(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))) = year(CURDATE())
and month(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))) = month(CURDATE())
```